# How to query database in SQL where there are two different cases?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a database using PostgreSQL with *TableA*:

```
{Name, Value, Id}    
{Bob, 0, 101}    
{Frank, 1, 102}    
{Jeff, 2, NULL}    
{Paul, 3, 103}
```

And *TableB*:

```
{Name, Value, Id}
{Bob, 0, 100}
{Bob, 0, 101}
{Frank, 1, 100}
{Frank, 1, 102}
```

I want to do

```
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.Id=TableB.Id
```

However, TableB doesn't show data where the Id=NULL.

I want to *return*:

```
{Bob, 0, 101}
{Frank, 1, 102}
{Jeff, 2, NULL}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @chris85 I dont think you can solve it with just  `JOIN`

Comment: What you're asking is unclear.  Why is inclusion of NULL id's okay in the result set, but id 103 is not? Neither has a match in table B.

Comment: TableA contains data for one set while TableB contains data for a completely different set, but the two tables can overlap.

Comment: why tableB has two `100` ? Is that a typo?

Comment: This is not a typo. The name Bob can hold two different Ids depending on what happened to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left` join, not an `inner`. An `inner` requires a match on the `left` table and the `right`. `NULL` will not match up.

```
select a.name, a.value, a.id FROM a 
left JOIN b 
ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24b08/4

Output:

```
Name    Value   Id
Bob     0       101
Frank   1       102
Jeff    2       (null)
```

Comment: Perfect. I actually have two JOINS in my SQL, but I didn't realize that I needed to do a LEFT JOIN on each of the two joins. When I first did it, I only did a LEFT JOIN on the first JOIN and an INNER JOIN on the second JOIN, which didn't work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It woks with the corrected data, the `A` wont look for the `100` because there is no `100` in it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b8c/3

Comment: @chris85 : your query will also return the row having `Id = 103`.

Comment: @Ullas Yea, that's correct. What's in `B` doesn't matter, `A` is the master, if there is a `B` match great we'll take that data. (My demo demonstrated the `103` return)

Comment: @chris85 : Because I have two LEFT JOINS, the data that contains a NULL Id will not contain any data from the second LEFT JOIN. Let's say I have LEFT JOIN TableC c ON b.state_id=c.state_id. How can I still get the state_id for the NULL id data?

Comment: @ButterJones What is `state_id`? Can you update the SQL fiddle so I can see what you are actually doing?

Comment: If you can have duplicated `id` in tableB you will have multiple rows. check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae9b1e/1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oh, you said two 101s previously I misread. Yes, I think that'd be the expected behavior though. OP wants where the `a.Id = b.Id`.

Comment: @chris85 : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942c79 Here is the updated fiddle with the new TableC.

Comment: Yes, that is why I try to explain, that cant be done with a single `JOIN`

Comment: @ButterJones You changed the column names, you need to change the `on`s to match the names. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942c79/2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oh yea, that wasn't my link though. My link has a functional link, or how I think it's suppose to work...

Answer (score 0):

Use ***[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html)***

**Query**

```
select * from TableA a
where exists(
    select 1 from TableB b
    where a.Id = b.Id
)
or a.Id is null;
```

***[`SQL Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3597/1)***

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql DEMO](http://rextester.com/LMUFH63912)**

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
  ON A.Name = B.Name
 AND A.Value = B.Value 
 AND A.Id = B.Id

UNION ALL

SELECT A.*
FROM TableA A
WHERE A.Id IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: This also works, except I ran into an issue doing a UNION on two tables of different number of columns because I'm pulling data from multiple tables.

Comment: Well this solve your question. Chris answer return extra rows. So either you make the wrong question or choose the wrong answer as correct.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza perhaps both